# How to show a busy message while angular digest is running

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

I have a complex page (lots of ng-repeats nested) so the digest takes a while to finish.  I want to give the user some feedback, so they don't think the browser is hung.

Below is a sample fiddle, when you click HIT ME the $watch hangs for 2 seconds. I want the "Working" message to show up, but it does not.

https://jsfiddle.net/jdhenckel/c7edvdt1/

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.n = 0;
    $scope.test = function() {
        $scope.msg = 'Working...';
      $scope.n += 1;
    };      
    $scope.$watch(function(scope) { 
      return $scope.n; 
    }, function() {
      var x = Date.now() + 2000;
      while (x > Date.now()) {}
        $scope.msg = 'Done.';
    });    
});
```

I also tried to use JQuery to directly change the DOM before the digest, but that also didn't work.  Seems like my only option is to move all the long running stuff a future digest using a $timeout, but that seems like a hack!

Is there an elegant way to notify the user that the digest is running?

**EDIT:** Here is a possibly more realistic example.

https://jsfiddle.net/jdhenckel/9vcLq0k3/

```
$scope.n = 0;
$scope.msg = 'Ready';
$scope.test = function() {
  $scope.msg = 'Working...';
  $timeout(function() {
    doStuff();
    $scope.msg = 'Done';
  }, 100);
}
```

This works because I moved all the expensive changes into `doStuff`.

I was hoping that Angular would provide a simpler way to do this (such as `ng-cloak` for initialization.)  If not, then I'll keep using $timeout.

Comment: Are you using any http request to get the data from server ?

Comment: you seem to have a big gap in understanding how the `$digest` cycle works, and what it is designed for.  the `$digest` cycle doesn't process data, it simply checks to see if anything that changed recently needs to be updated in the DOM.  If the `$digest` cycle ***truly*** took 2 seconds, this approach would be counter productive, since changing `$scope.msg` would trigger *another* `$digest`;  I suspect your issues are something larger.

Comment: in this case, your code changes the `$scope.msg` variable, which triggers a `$digest` cycle to occur and update the DOM as soon as the processing finishes.  The `$scope.watch` is then triggered, so the next `$digest` cycle doesn't happen yet.  the `$scope.watch` runs a **blocking** process for 2 seconds, then changes `$scope.watch` again, which would trigger the next `$digest` cycle, except there is already one queued.  that next `$digest` then goes off, and updates the DOM to the *current* value of `$scope.msg`, which now happens to be the same as it was previously, since it changed twice.

Comment: No I am not getting data from the server. Sorry if my toy example is confusing. Imagine a page that is very complex (lots of nested ng-repeats with ng-hide/show/class/etc) such that the digest takes a while to update the DOM..... how can I give the user a "Working" message in that case????

Comment: the digest wouldn't take a long time to update the DOM unless there are *lots* of changes happening all at once, and even then, redrawing the entire DOM isn't a processing intense process;  in every example I've ever seen, performance people blame on the `$digest` is actually something external to angular.  If you are truly having performance issues, your best bet is to show a [mcve] of your actual setup, rather than trying to create some false example that doesn't even demonstrate the problem you are faced with.

Comment: @Claies, see my edit

Comment: right, that seems like a better example, but it continues to highlight that the problem is not with `$digest`, it is with other application logic which is modifying your data.  in this case, you could achieve the same thing with a promise, rather than `$timeout`, but I don't have an example written to show this at the second.